# Emulator flutter (Android studio)

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

How to download an iPad emulator, I searched for it in android studio but I didn't find it.

Can it be downloaded directly from the internet? I would like a link if possible

Comment: ios simulator only can found and download and use in Xcode.

Comment: You need  macOS system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any type of iOS or macOS Emulator / Stimulator you need MacOS .

And if you have one you can simply download XCode and there you will have option to download iOS SDK and run its Stimulator .

Comment: Oh, I'm using Windows

Comment: Then there is no possible way. You can't use iOS Emulator